# Installing Ruby 1.9.1 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, package-managers, ubuntu-9.04

I wonder about installing the latest version of Ruby on Ubuntu 9.04. Now I can run through the `./configure` and `make` stuff fine, but what I wonder about: how to avoid conflicts with the packaging system? For example if some other package I install depends on Ruby, wouldn't the package manager install the (outdated) Ruby package and in the worst case overwrite my files?

So I think I need some way to tell Ubuntu that Ruby is in fact already installed?

Comment: So, out of pure curiosity, is there any reason to have the absolute latest version of ruby? I mean it's great to be bleeding edge, but is there actually any features that you need that this newest version has that the older versions don't? If there isn't, it seems a bit unnecessary to upgrade.

Comment: I think so - it has unicode support, for one thing, is much faster, and supposedly has fixed some memory leaks of the older versions. I am not a specialist on Ruby, though. However, I am developing on a Mac and I noticed that Ruby 1.9.1 that comes with MacPorts is not compatible with the 1.9.0 version that comes with Ubuntu. Unicode really is the biggie for me, though. I heard that it works in Rails with Ruby 1.8, but I couldn't get any definite info on it. Also I don't have only Rails apps, also standalone Ruby.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.1 (patch 243) ships as a package in karmic koala.

Comment: it's quite odd that even for ubuntu 10.10 ruby 1.9.1 shows as virtual.  Why can't you just install it with apt?  weirdness.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Save yourself the headache and use [RVM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) ([Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io/%E2%80%8E))

Keep in mind, Rails 3 works best with Ruby 1.9.2. Ruby 1.9.2 fixes up quite a few bugs in 1.9.1 and is preferable to running 1.9.1.

With RVM installing 1.9.2 is a breeze.

Comment: +1000 I finally got around to trying this on OSX today, and it's brilliant. This page was particularly helpful: http://www.rubyinside.com/rvm-ruby-version-manager-2347.html

Comment: My world has been ROCKED! I should have checked into this sooner. =] RVM is awesome!

Comment: while `rvm install 1.9.1` seems like a nice and friendly command, it led me down a horrible two hour long trail of broken patches.  Save your sanity, just install it from apt-get.  rvm is nice when it works like most everything ruby.

Comment: `rvm` is a very complicated beast. While it make work for some, I wasted half a day with it. Ubuntu 12.10 comes with Ruby 1.9.3, so there is little reason to mess with `rvm`.

Comment: @RossSmithII I am curious to hear why this played up for you, I bet you tried installing rvm with sudo

Comment: I've spent almost all day trying to install ruby using rvm on Ubuntu 12.10, and I didn't use sudo. mapasis was very helpful in #rvm. I think we found a solution, and if it reliably works, I will post to https://rvm.io/

Comment: This saved me from the horror! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395

Answer (score 34):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

(http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)

Comment: ruby -v still gives version 1.8.7.

Comment: You might need to `sudo apt-get remove ruby`

Comment: "sudo apt-get remove ruby" does not work for me, I am using ubuntu 11.10 beta. but "sudo apt-get autoremove" works just fine. and after then, ruby -v will give me 1.9.2. (I was installing ruby1.9.2-full)

Comment: You also need to run `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby` to change the default to 1.9.x. No need to uninstall 1.8. (As per my answer to this question).

Answer (score 28):

After running

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

It's solution is to run the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
```

Then you will get this output:

```
   There are 2 choices for the alternative ruby (providing /usr/bin/ruby).

     Selection    Path                Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   * 0            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        auto mode
     1            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        manual mode
     2            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   10        manual mode

   Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
   update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 to provide /usr/bin/ruby (ruby) in    manual mode.
   $ ruby --version
   ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

Credit for this solution goes to person who answered https://askubuntu.com/questions/91693/how-do-you-uninstall-ruby-1-8-7-and-install-ruby-1-9-2 .  Currently the ruby1.9.1 package is actually ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Thanks for this - I just blew half a day uninstalling, re-installing, compiling and recompiling from source, then using rvm, all the while wondering why 'ruby -v' doggedly kept returning 1.8.7. I don't know why this isn't at the least on the RVM install page.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full` doesnt work anymore

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ruby-full` is probably the install command these days (I haven't tried that out yet though).

Answer (score 7):

The way I did it was to build it using checkinstall which lets you build a deb package. So I downloaded the Ruby 1.9.1 source, did a "configure" and then "make", did a "checkinstall" and made the package name ruby1.9 so it installs as if it were a new version of ruby 1.9 (as it should).

Answer (score 4):

I got the Ruby specific info from [this](http://74.125.77.132/search?q=cache:zAwFMmM0DqIJ:kekova.ca/articles/2005/10/23/how-to-install-ruby-and-gems-and-rails-on-linux-for-non-root-non-expert-users+ruby+install+prefix&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl) site.
You can install most software in a different directory with the --prefix=/path switch. And it is common to install in /opt/ for everyone on your pc, or in $HOME if it is only for you.

For installing in /opt:

```
$ ./configure –prefix=/opt/ruby
$ make install
```

If you want to use the /opt installed ruby, edit you ~/.bashrc and add

```
export PATH=/opt/ruby/bin/:$PATH
```

If you don't want to have the custom Ruby build as default, you can add this to your ~/.bashrc instead of the former command

```
function setupruby {
     export PATH=/opt/ruby/bin/:$PATH
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful - at least that way I can avoid the conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short and convenient way to install 1.9.1 and to make it default:
http://michalf.me/blog:make-ruby-1-9-default-on-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala

Answer (score 1):

I created a launchpad ppa for ruby 1.9.2. Details in the links below

http://www.humbug.in/2010/launchpad-ppa-for-ruby-1-9-2-and-some-ruby-bindings/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pratikmsinha/ruby192+bindings
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/; sudo mv pratikmsinha-ruby192+bindings-lucid.list pratikmsinha-ruby192bindings-lucid.list
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.2
```

Comment: I have added the ruby 1.9.2 final build to my ppa

Comment: Read more about it here http://www.humbug.in/2010/ruby-1-9-2-final-build-for-ubuntu-lucid-uploaded-to-launchpad-ppa/

Answer (score 0):

Looking through Synaptic it seems like you don't even have to deal with the Multiverse or third-party repositories.  But since `sudo apt-get install ruby` currently installs an alias to `ruby1.8`, you should install `ruby1.9` explicitly – manually or via the repositories – and create the alias `ruby` yourself.

You may want to put the binary in `/usr/bin` since that's where the distribution would put it anyway.  Anywhere on your PATH is fine, though.

Comment: My impression was that in the repositories there is only Ruby 1.9.0, which seems to be incomptible with Ruby 1.9.1. However, 1.9.1 is supposed to be the final release, 1.9.0 is just development version from whenever.

Comment: You're right.  Looks like you'll have to build it yourself for now.