# How do I install the latest version of ruby in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I currently have ruby version 1.8.2 in my machine and I would like to upgrade it to 1.9.2. How am i supposed to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ruby 1.9.1 on Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109695/installing-ruby-1-9-1-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you running? I am running 11.04 and Ruby 1.9.1 is available in Synaptic package manager.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I use Ubuntu, and I've found the easiest way to install newer versions of Ruby is to use rvm.

The instructions are here: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Basically, it installs different versions of Ruby locally for the user and updates environment variables for Ruby and gems based on which version you decide to use.

It's this easy:

```
jim@schubert:~$ rvm use system
Now using system ruby.
jim@schubert:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
jim@schubert:~$ gem -v
1.3.7
jim@schubert:~$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /home/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
jim@schubert:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
jim@schubert:~$ gem -v
1.5.2
jim@schubert:~$
```

Answer (score 16):

I don't like having RVM on production server, so I usually install ruby from source with an install script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp_dir="/tmp"
version="2.2.3"
minor_version="2.2"
ruby_version="ruby-$version"

echo "*******************"
echo "* Installing Ruby *"
echo "*******************"

sudo apt-get install -y autoconf build-essential libreadline-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev

mkdir -p "$tmp_dir"
cd "$tmp_dir"

wget "http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/$minor_version/$ruby_version.tar.gz"
tar -xvzf $ruby_version.tar.gz
cd $ruby_version

./configure --disable-install-doc
make --jobs `nproc`
sudo make install

cd ..
rm $ruby_version.tar.gz
rm -rf $ruby_version

echo "*******************"
echo "* Ruby installed! *"
echo "*******************"
```

Comment: Yup. I don't want RVM on my server either. Good work.

Answer (score 13):

1 Install RVM:

> https://rvm.io

2 Then install Ruby 1.9.2

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 7):

Since the original question was about the latest version, here is how to get Ruby 2.2.

```
apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
apt-get update
apt-get install ruby2.2
```

Here is how to get Ruby 2.3.

```
apt-get install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev
```

[Info](https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/) on brightbox's  maintainance of these.

Comment: Doesn't get latest patch version.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sudo apt-get install ruby-full` you will get
old version of ruby (1.9) currently existing in Ubuntu repos.
You might want to check installation from [source](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source)

Download ruby tar from [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and then run:

```
$ tar -xf ruby-X.X.X.tar.gz
$ cd ruby-X.X.X
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

In some cases you will need to realod bash by typing:

```
$ bash
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what Ubuntu version you are running, you can get the ruby packages with this link http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ruby1.9.1&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all, to get the latest Ruby(1.9.2-p290) installed, you have to upgrade your Ubuntu to oneiric, if you don't like to upgrade your system, maybe you have to install Ruby with RVM as fl00r answered.

Answer (score 2):

I might came late but this is a very useful website that provides Ubuntu packages and it seems to be maintained and up-to-date. Look [here](https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you! Note that `apt` may not install the *latest* Ruby version automatically, because the `brightbox.com` repository may specify an earlier version as preferred. For example, if `apt install ruby` installs `ruby2.3` but you want 2.4, be explicit, e.g., `apt install ruby2.4`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check stackoverflow more carefully before asking questions.

[Installing Ruby 1.9.1 on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109695/installing-ruby-1-9-1-on-ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```