# why my ruby version is still an old version on ubuntu after I installed ruby1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ruby-1.9

I am newbie to ubuntu and ROR. After installed latest ruby1.9.2 with apt-get, type "ruby -v" it still shows up old version ruby1.8.7. I tried to reinstall with rvm, nothing changed.

As mentioned in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109695/installing-ruby-1-9-1-on-ubuntu), I tried to remove ruby, and reinstall ruby1.9.1-full... still the same thing...

What else I can do about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ubuntu uses a something called alternatives for chosing between two version of similar executable. Running

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
```

and chosing the ruby you want should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

I'm using RVM myself, but if I remember correctly, ruby1.8 and ruby1.9 can be installed side by side on Ubuntu. `ruby` is just a symbolic link which points to version 1.8 by default - which should be called `ruby1.8` and stored in the same directory. 1.9 will be called `ruby1.9`.

So just find where `ruby` symbolic link is (`whereis ruby`) and change it so it points to `ruby1.9`.

```
sudo rm /path/ruby
sudo ln -s /path/ruby1.9 /path/ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using rvm, but still referencing system ruby. To switch, you have to tell rvm what version to use.

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

This will switch your current environment only. So ruby -v in your current shell will use the right version. (you should probably go with 1.9.3, FWIW) If you want to always use that ruby be default, you type:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

If you want to switch back to system ruby, you can use:

```
rvm use system
```

Comment: what does the command "which ruby" tell you? It should point to a binary in the rvm directory. If not, your rvm is probably set up wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the package of Ruby version at apt-get repository is an old version.

I suggest use [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) to install the latest version.

Here is a great tutorial using rbenv to install the latest Ruby version from Digital Ocean:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9
```

should do the trick.

You can find what libraries are available to install by

```
apt-cache search <your search term>
```

So I just did `apt-cache search ruby | grep 9` to find it.

You'll probably need to invoke the new Ruby as ruby1.9, because Ubuntu will probably default to 1.8 if you just type ruby.